# The app is not showing on full screen on iPhone after update the iOS version 13.3 but it is showing before update the iOS version 12.4

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ios12, visual-studio-mac, ios13.3

Please find below screenshot, The mobile app developed in Xamarin.form cross platform c# using Visual Studio 2019 Mac.
The issue is, earlier the app is showing full screen on iPhone iOS with version 12.4 but after update iPhone iOS version with 13.3 it is not showing on full screen, showing some gap on bottom of screen.

Kindly suggest me any solutions.

[image: screenshot of mobile app]

Comment: Post the code you got... I suspect u are hiding the NavigationBar programmatically. NavigationBar setup has changed a little since iOS 13.x, could be that your custom layouting methods don't get a reference to the navigation bar and therefore wrongly render the space needed for the page

Comment: If you are showing the ViewController using present API then there is a new modal presentation style introduced in iOS 13.x. Use fullscreen for modalPresentationStyle before present your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Open file "info.plist" in iOS project and add Property "Launch screen interface file base name" and set value to "LaunchScreen". If the file already has a property with this value, you can remove it.